# PHP - Não está a verificar todos os elseif's ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php, mysql

Boas, estou criando um sistema de registo com verificação para testes para ser implementado num site. O problema é que a verificação atribui-me um erro devido a multiplos elseif num if... será que só posso usar um elseif? e como faço para conseguir varios sem destruir o meu metodo de verificação? Vou deixar o meu codigo aqui.

```html
<?php
//conectar base de dados

//Variaveis
$Host = "localhost";
$User = "root";
$Password = "";
$DB = "RL";

//Ligação
$link = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password, $DB);

//Condição
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}else {
    echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;
        
        if(isset($_POST["BTN_Teste"])){
            //Variaveis De Input
            $Usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
            $Email = $_POST['Email'];
            $Pass1 = $_POST['Pass1'];
            $Pass2 = $_POST['Pass2'];

            //funcoes de procuras
            $Procura_U = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Usuario='$Usuario'";
            $Procura_E = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$Email'";

            //Resultados de funcoes de procuras
            $Res_U = mysqli_query($link, $Procura_U) or die(mysqli_error($link));
            $Res_E = mysqli_query($link, $Procura_E) or die(mysqli_error($link));

            //Verificação de user e email e senha
            if($Pass1 != $Pass2){
                $Input_erro3 = "Senhas Não Coincidem!";
            }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($Res_U) > 0){
                $Input_erro1 = "Usuário Já Registado!";
            }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($Res_E) > 0){
                $Input_erro2 = "Email Já Registado!";
            }else{
                //Confirmação de senhas e encriptação md5
                if($Pass1 === $Pass2){
                    $Pass3 = md5($Pass2);
                    //Funções de inserção
                    $Inserir = "INSERT INTO Users (Usuario, Email, Senha) VALUES('$Usuario', '$Email', '$Pass3')";
                    $Res_Inserir = mysqli_query($link, $Inserir) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "Registado Com Sucesso!";
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }else{
            //Divisao da mensagem de sucesso da base de dados
            echo"<br>"; 
            echo "Botao Registar Não Clicado!";
        }
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">
    <title>Registo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <span>Usuário</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="Usuario" placeholder="Usuário" id="" required>
            <?php
            //Exibir Mensagem De Erro
            if(isset($_POST["BTN_Teste"])){
                if(mysqli_num_rows($Res_U) > 0){
                    echo"<br>";
                    echo"<div class='Erro'>";
                    echo $Input_erro1;
                    echo"</div>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            <br>
            <span>E-mail</span><br>
            <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" id="" required>
            <?php
            //Exibir Mensagem De Erro
            if(isset($_POST["BTN_Teste"])){
                if(mysqli_num_rows($Res_E) > 0){
                    echo"<br>";
                    echo"<div class='Erro'>";
                    echo $Input_erro2;
                    echo"</div>";
                }
            }
            ?><br><br>
            <span>Senha</span><br>
            <input type="password" name="Pass1" placeholder="Senha" id="" required>
            <br><br>
            <span>Confirmação de Senha</span><br>
            <input type="password" name="Pass2" placeholder="Senha" id="" required>
            <?php
            //Exibir Mensagem De Erro
            if(isset($_POST["BTN_Teste"])){
                if($Pass1 != $Pass2){
                    echo"<br>";
                    echo"<div class='Erro'>";
                    echo $Input_erro3;
                    echo"</div>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            <br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="BTN_Teste" value="Registar">
        </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

E O Style.css

```css
.Erro input{
    border:1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(77, 221, 33);
}
.Erro{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
    width: 10.5em;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(221, 33, 33);
}
input{
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 60, 255, 0.315);
}
```

E A Base De Dados

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.5
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: 06-Maio-2019 às 21:42
-- Versão do servidor: 10.1.38-MariaDB
-- versão do PHP: 7.3.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `rl`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `rl` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `rl`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Usuario` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Senha` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `Usuario`, `Email`, `Senha`) VALUES
(1, 'Teste', 'Polimpo4@hotmail.com', '317d7b01d3a11b214e9cdc429f0feea3');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Só não achei a mensagem de erro, coloca a mensagem que você comentou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal é você utilizar as estruturas lógicas para identificar os resultados incorretos. Você não tem limite de usos para `if` e `elseif` mas isso prejudica a legibilidade do seu código.

Para deixar o código mais legível, você pode escrevê-lo da seguinte forma:

```
//Verificação de user e email e senha    
if (mysqli_num_rows($Res_U) > 0) {
    $Input_erro1 = "Usuário Já Registado!";
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($Res_E) > 0) {
    $Input_erro2 = "Email Já Registado!";
}

//Confirmação de senhas e encriptação md5
if ($Pass1 === $Pass2) {          
    $Pass3 = md5($Pass2);
    $Inserir = "INSERT INTO Users (Usuario, Email, Senha) VALUES('$Usuario', '$Email', '$Pass3')";

    //Função de inserção
    $Res_Inserir = mysqli_query($link, $Inserir) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    echo "<br>";
    echo "Registado Com Sucesso!";
    exit();

} else {
    $Input_erro3 = "Senhas Não Coincidem!";
}
```

É interessante também pesquisar sobre [boas práticas](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) de programação com a linguagem PHP para aperfeiçoar a sua maneira de escrever os códigos.